# Skype [4.2.0.11] - black Video on KDE - 13.04 32bit

Tags: 13.04, kde, skype, qt

I have this strange issue with skype:

- using Unity and other DE ( lxde/E17 ) everything works fine
- using KDE/BE::Shell I have black screen in the video/webcam box ( also in option in video tab)

I suspect that the issue is caused by some missing library to be loaded so I have tried this fix but without any success:

- `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype &`

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 32bit and skype version is  4.2.0.11

**UPDATE:**
I have just tried the dynamic package and I have the same issue with it, now I'm confused about what could be the cause QT ? or some other LIBS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me is adding:

```
<VideoRenderer>
  <DisableXv>1</DisableXv>
  <ForceOpenGL>1</ForceOpenGL>
</VideoRenderer>
```

to the `UI` section of the file `~/.Skype/[username]/config.xml`.

Comment: `<DisableXv>1</DisableXv>` this is what really make the difference